# super().__init__() of subclass failing when using metaclass that inherits another metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three classes, `Token`, `Word` and `Type` for a little compiler written in Python 3 that I am doing as part of CS course. My goal is to have a static variable that points to instances of those same classes in `Word` and `Type`.

To achieve it, I am trying to use metaclasses. As follows:

```
from lexer.tag import Tag

class MetaWord(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        cls.and_ = cls('&&', Tag.AND)
        cls.or_ = cls("||", Tag.OR)     


class MetaType(MetaWord):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        cls.int_ = cls('int', Tag.BASIC, 4)
        cls.float_ = cls('float', Tag.BASIC, 8)


class Token:
    def __init__(self, tag_id):
        self.tag = tag_id


class Word(Token, metaclass=MetaWord):
    def __init__(self, lexeme, tag_id):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(tag_id)
        self.lexeme = lexeme


class Type(Word, metaclass=MetaType):
    def __init__(self, word, tag_id, w):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(word, tag_id)        
        self.width = w
```

Running the `Word` class it works just fine, but when I try to instantiate the `Type` class, in the line:

```
cls.int_ = cls('int', Tag.BASIC, 4)
```

I get: `{TypeError}:__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tag_id'`

Debugging, I found that the error is raising in the `__init__` method of the `Word` class:

```
super(self.__class__, self).__init__(tag_id)
```

If I call the above line without any arguments in `__init__`, I get:

```
{TypeError}:__init__() missing 2 required positional argument: 'lexeme' and 'tag_id'
```

If I pass these two arguments, like:

```
super(self.__class__, self).__init__('int', tag_id)
```

I get again:

```
{TypeError}:__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tag_id'
```

And if I try to pass all 3 arguments of `Type`:

```
super(self.__class__, self).__init__('int', tag_id, 4)
```

I get:

```
{TypeError}__init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I can't understand this behavior, it seems the class can't find which is the **init**() method of the `Token` class, or that the `__init__()` method of the metaclasses are breaking something. How can I fix it?

Comment: `MetaType.__init__` is skipping the superclass `__init__`.

Comment: **Never pass `self.__class__` to `super`.** If it was that simple, they never would have required the type parameter for `super` in the first place.

Comment: If you're using Python 3.x, as your tag and the use of `metaclass=` suggests, just use `super().__init__(...)`.

Comment: If I dont pass anything to `super()`, I get `RuntimeError: super(): empty __class__ cell`

Comment: To go with @user2357112's comment, `self.__class__` refers to the type of the runtime argument `self`, which is not necessarily the class currently being defined.

Comment: If I pass the current class, it says its not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was indeed, as the comments suggested, invoking `super()` without parameters.

The problem was that when I removed parameters from `super()` I was getting the error

```
RuntimeError: super(): empty __class__ cell
```

Upon some research, I found that this error is a bug in python 3, that was [fixed in version `3.6`](https://bugs.python.org/issue23722)

Updating my python version to 3.6 fixed the problem.

Comment: Note that replacing `self.__class__` with the correct static class would also work, for reasons I can’t explain by typing on my phone. (Maybe my home internet will start working later tonight.)